# How to use material.SetColorArray with Shader Graph?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

A Material `material` has 2 methods: `material.SetColorArray` and `material.GetColorArray`.

How do I use these things if my material wraps a shader made in Shader Graph?